# Commiting Changes (WFS-T) Problem with Base Layer (Error Found: outside of (-180.0,180.0))

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, geoext

Committing changes stops working after changing the basemap from OSM (as a WMS) to Bing maps (or Google or even OSM as a "OpenLayers.Layer.OSM")  PS: All my layers are on 3857
Here's the Error :

```
...
ext>org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: -375375
.85085794 outside of (-180.0,180.0)
Parsing failed for LineString: org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection
.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: -375375.85085794 outside of (-180.0,180.0)
org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: -375375.85085794 outside
of (-180.0,180.0)
...
```

(See the screenshots) [image: With OSM]
[image: Update of the BingMaps]

```
...
store: new GeoExt.data.WMSCapabilitiesStore({
url:
"/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1",
autoLoad: true
}),
},
...    
extent: OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray([
-389443.8438372187,3795830.778190598 ,
-361613.60599175736,3828780.6685322397
]),

layers: [new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
name: "Bing Hybrid",
key: "AtiDbrNiSbYFAW0azuAZHQLgk5ULkZIOqWyKW4IfkY9q3uhDuCZh6Av7aOOUOs9Q",
type: "AerialWithLabels",
Projection : "EPSG:3857"
})
/*
new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
         "OpenStreetMap WMS",
        "https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?",
        {layers: 'OSM-WMS'}
        )
new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
"Google Satellite", {
type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, 
 numZoomLevels: 25
})*/],

});
...

text: "Save",
handler: function() {
    app.featureGrid.store.proxy.protocol.commit(
        vectorLayer.features, {
            callback: function() {
                selectedLayer.redraw(true);
                    app.featureGrid.store.reload();
                                    }
                                });
            }
}]});

    ...
var schema = new GeoExt.data.AttributeStore({
url: url,
baseParams: {
"SERVICE": "WFS",
"REQUEST": "DescribeFeatureType",
"VERSION": "1.1.0",
"TYPENAME": layer.params.LAYERS
},
autoLoad: true,
listeners: {
"load": function(store) {
app.featureGrid.setTitle(layer.name);
selectedLayer = layer;
configureGrid(store, url);
}
}
});

...

app.featureGrid.reconfigure(new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
autoLoad: true,
proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
url: url,
version: "1.1.0",
featureType: rawAttributeData.featureTypes[0].typeName,
featureNS: rawAttributeData.targetNamespace,
srsName: "EPSG:3857",
geometryName: geometryName,
maxFeatures: 25000,
})
}),
fields: fields
}),

...
```

Comment: How to help if you paste here all these code lines ?

Comment: Thanks for your response, That's the problem, I don't know where it is, since it works fine with OSM but not Bing or Google map...

Comment: We really need to see the xml you're posting to geoserver and what the error is

Comment: How can I get it for you?

Comment: I always get downvoted... What's not clear about my question? ask me to edit it (i did) rather than just block it for me.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but it looks like you have presented all your code rather than a snippet, and you say it "don't work" but not whether the symptom is an error message or something else. Please keep editing your question to improve it - there is more help about asking good questions in links from the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @PolyGeo How can I put a bounty in this question with my little reputation?

Comment: @WKT Here's the Response :ext>org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: -375375
.85085794 outside of (-180.0,180.0)
Parsing failed for LineString: org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection
.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: -375375.85085794 outside of (-180.0,180.0)
org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: -375375.85085794 outside
of (-180.0,180.0)

Comment: Until you get enough reputation to afford the minimum bounty of 50 offering one will not be an option for you. Well received answers and questions are the quickest way to build reputation but well considered edits to the posts of others can help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually pretty easy !
All I had to do is set "projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857")" in the MapPanel section.

```
...
map: {
numZoomLevels: 25,
controls: controls,
projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857")
},
...
```

Comment: Nope, I was talking about Bing Maps and Google Maps, not OSM

Comment: My WMS Layer was already in 3857, in fact All the layers and the Base Maps were in 3857, The trick here is to set the "map" in 3857 too, and by "Map" I mean the openlayers environment that I work on. Basically it had nothing as a projection (or 4326 as default).

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue is projections - OpenLayers sets the projection of the map to match the projection of the base layer. Google and Bing will  (always) use epsg:3857 while the OSM server you have chosen is a WMS server and if you check the [GetCapabilities](https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?service=wms&request=getCapabilities) you will see it can serve maps in the following projections:

```
<SRS>EPSG:900913</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:3857</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:25832</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:25833</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:29192</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:29193</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:31466</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:31467</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:31468</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:32648</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:4674</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:3068</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:2100</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:3034</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:3035</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:31463</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:4258</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:4839</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:2180</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:21781</SRS>
<SRS>EPSG:2056</SRS>
```

I suspect (but haven't checked) that OpenLayers defaults to epsg:4326 (lat/lon) if you don't specify what you want the projection of a WMS layer to be. There are two possible fixes:

1. use the OpenLayers [OSM layer](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/OSM-js.html) which will use 3857 or
2. set the projection of your [WMS layer](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html) to epsg:3857.

Comment: Thank you for your response, The problem isn't with the OSM actually, Editing with an OSM as a Base layer is Irrelevant. I need Either Google Sat or Bing Maps and in order to do so, I Projected all my work to the EPSG:3857 without success with it.